# problema con saltos de linea en fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

el documento pdf se me  crea bien pero necesito en un parte saltos de lineal y no se por que no me los acepta, allí les dejo el codig0, lo tengo funcionando en la siguiente pagina https://dinervent.com/reme/prueba.php y marque (aquí necesito ayuda con los saltos de lineal) para que vean donde tengo el problema por favor se los agradezco de antemano.

estoy atento si necesitan alguna info adicional, si se fijan en la parte de la direccion si me agarra los \n pero en la parte que necesito no me los agarra

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');




        $Direct_fact = "$Direccion, $Nom_zona_urb, $Nom_municipio, $Nom_depart, $Nom_provincia, $Nom_pais";

        $Direct_facturacion = wordwrap($Direct_fact, 50, "\n" ,FALSE);

        $Datos_desc = "recarga recibida por $Cant_bol Bs";

        $Descripcion_pdf = wordwrap($Datos_desc, 50, "\n" ,FALSE);

        $pdf = new FPDF($orientation='P',$unit='mm');
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',35);    
        $textypos = 5;
        $pdf->setY(12);
        $pdf->setX(10);
        

        
        
        // Agregamos los datos de la empresa
        $pdf->MultiCell(0,$textypos,"DINERVENT, C.A.");
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);    
        $pdf->setY(19);$pdf->setX(10);
        $pdf->MultiCell(0,$textypos,"RIF: J-500952716");
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);    
        
        
        // Agregamos los datos del cliente
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);    
        $pdf->setY(30);$pdf->setX(10);
        $pdf->MultiCell(0,$textypos,"PARA:");
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);    
        $pdf->setY(35);$pdf->setX(10);
        $pdf->MultiCell(0,$textypos,"$NomE");
        $pdf->setY(40);$pdf->setX(10);
        $pdf->MultiCell(0,$textypos,"$Tipo_doc_empre - $Numero_documento");
        $pdf->setY(45);$pdf->setX(10);
        $pdf->MultiCell(0,$textypos,"$Num_telefono");
        $pdf->setY(50);$pdf->setX(10);
        $pdf->MultiCell(0,$textypos,"$Direct_facturacion");



        
        // Agregamos los datos del cliente
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);    
        $pdf->setY(30);$pdf->setX(135);
        $pdf->MultiCell(0,$textypos,"RECIBO # $max_val_recibo");
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);    
        $pdf->setY(35);$pdf->setX(135);
        $pdf->MultiCell(0,$textypos,"Fecha: $fecha_recibo");
        $pdf->setY(40);$pdf->setX(135);
        $pdf->MultiCell(0,$textypos,"");
        $pdf->setY(50);$pdf->setX(135);
        $pdf->MultiCell(0,$textypos,"");
        
        
        
        /// Apartir de aqui empezamos con la tabla de productos
        $pdf->setY(60);$pdf->setX(135);
            $pdf->Ln();
        /////////////////////////////
        //// Array de Cabecera
        $header = array("Descripcion","Tasa BCV","Monto a acreditar","Bolivares recibidos");
        //// Arrar de Productos
        $products = array(
            array($Descripcion_pdf,$Mont_tasa,$Cant_recarga,$Cant_bol),
        );
            // Column widths
            $w = array(85, 20, 40, 40);

            
            $pdf->Cell(85,7,"Descripcion",1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(20,7,"Tasa BCV",1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(40,7,"Monto a acreditar",1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Cell(40,7,"Bolivares recibidos",1,0,'C');

            $pdf->Ln();



            $pdf->Cell(85,25,"$Descripcion_pdf",1,0,'L');
            $pdf->Cell(20,25,"$Mont_tasa",1,0,'R');
            $pdf->Cell(40,25,"$ $Cant_recarga",1,0,'R');
            $pdf->Cell(40,25,"Bs  $Cant_bol",1,0,'R');
            $pdf->Ln();
    
    
            $link = "https://www.dinervent.com/reme/p/$Archivo_rec";
        


            $pdf->Cell(185,7,"Datos bancarios donde realizo el pago",1,0,'C');
            $pdf->Ln();



            $pdf->Cell(185,14,"$Dat_recarg aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \n aaaaaa \n aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa \n aaaaaaa dddddds",1,0,'L');
            $pdf->Ln();


            $pdf->Cell(20, 10, 'Link Ref', 1, 1,'C', false, $link);
            $pdf->Ln();



        /////////////////////////////
        //// Apartir de aqui esta la tabla con los subtotales y totales

        $pdf->setY(118);
        $pdf->setX(115);

        $pdf->Cell(40,10,"Total",1,0,'C');
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,"$Cant_bol",1,0,'R');
        $pdf->Ln();



        /////////////////////////////
        
        
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);    
        
        $pdf->setY(131);
        $pdf->setX(10);
        $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"Direccion: .");
        
        $pdf->setY(136);
        $pdf->setX(10);
        $pdf->Cell(5,$textypos,"Telefono: 0241-87.");
        

$pdf->Output('F', 'recibos/'.$Nom_pdf);
```

Comment: No entiendo mucho la lógica que intentas reflejar al crear tu array `$products`, lo cierto es que el texto al que quieres aplicar saltos de línea se encuentra en la posición `[0][0]` de ese array. Entonces, puedes hacer algo como esto: **`$text=explode("\n",$products[0][0]); foreach ($text as $txt) { $pdf->Write($txt); $pdf->Ln(); }`**

Comment: disculpa tiene el array por que lo baje de un ejemplo por internet pero el echo es que alli no necesito ningun array realmente solo un tabla de dos finas, 4 columnas y el totoal pero no logrado quitar ese array, soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: ¿Una tabla de dos filas y 4 columnas con qué contenido exactamente?

Comment: el contenido lo bajaría de la base de datos, una de ellas tiene numero de cuentas y nombres entonces puede tener unas tres líneas por eso es que tengo el problema con el salto de linea, voy a probar con el codigo que me envio.

Comment: Ya, pero si es contenido dinámico, lo que tienes es que implementar una forma que te ponga los saltos de línea de forma dinámica, allí donde los necesites. Ahora bien, sin saber cómo está estructurada la respuesta que recibes de la BD, poco podremos ayudarte.

Comment: cuesta tanto hacer una tabla en HTML y pasarle el codigo html como parte del cuerpo ?

Comment: ok e editado el código, quite los array, en la parte donde necesito hacer el salto de lineal es en donde están los \n ya que el tengo escrito es muy largo y se me sale del documento en vez de ir a la linea de abajo y continuar